# Fetching data from investing.com

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch real-time data from https://investing.com/indices/major-indices with php and I'm able to get the data, but for some reason the data is not accurate - it seems like there's a delay and I'm getting previous data instead of current real-time data.

Any ideas why?

I'm using stream_context_create to get it:

```
$url = "https://www.investing.com/indices/major-indices";

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST'
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: How should we know? All your PHP code does is make a HTTP request to the mentioned URL. There's nothing in that which would inherently cause the server to return different data. The only other issue from your side could be if you're somehow processing/storing/displaying the data incorrectly, but you haven't shown us anything about that. If you visit this site from a tool such as PostMan do you also get the same unexpected response? If so, then the issue isn't in your PHP code, and you should probably contact the API vendor for support.

Comment: P.S. In future when asking a question here, please ensure that what you post consists of a [mre] of the issue you're facing. I would be 99% sure that in this case, your code doesn't do that. See also [ask] for further guidance. Thanks.

Comment: N.B. As far as I can tell, your request would download the entire HTML of the page you mentioned, rather than any structured data.  I wouldn't call that an API. An API would return JSON or XML or something like that, rather than HTML intended for displaying in a browser. It's So it's unclear how you're processing / extracting anything meaningful from it? Are you simply re-displaying the entire thing as the output of your script? If so then I guess it's not impossible that some caching is going on somewhere.

Comment: You should use [a real API](https://nordicapis.com/10-real-time-stock-data-apis/). They are made for this purpose. The reason you don't get accurate data is because the page you download is constantly updated through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As the other comments suggest, you should use an API for this instead of fetching from the web page, which itself is probably fetching from an API.

It didn't take long for me to find the following unofficial API package on GitHub, albeit it is for NPM (NodeJS - Javascript). It is well maintained and updated only 7 days ago.

[Investing.com Unofficial API NPM Package](https://github.com/DavideViolante/investing-com-api)

If you're tied to PHP and can't or won't change, it doesn't look like there is an official investing.com API so you'd need to use something different, perhaps from Kiko's suggestion.

Update:

Further analysis of this package shows that it's simply returning JSON from the following API URLs:
`https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/${pairId}/historical/chart?period=${period}&interval=${interval}&pointscount=${pointscount}`

See it in the code [here](https://github.com/DavideViolante/investing-com-api/blob/ddd281fda5cf567f07bdcfd4ae4ed23f83cbe0c6/index.js#L47)

Comment: Further analysis of this package shows that it's simply returning JSON from the following API URLs:

`https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/${pairId}/historical/chart?period=${period}&interval=${interval}&pointscount=${pointscount}`

See it in the code [here](https://github.com/DavideViolante/investing-com-api/blob/ddd281fda5cf567f07bdcfd4ae4ed23f83cbe0c6/index.js#L47)

Comment: You know you can [edit] your answer to include useful info like that? Better than hiding it below the line in the comments :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have done that - wasn't thinking :)

Comment: wow,...... noobie programmer here. I am also trying to scrape data from there, and this api URL will prove crazily useful. But do you guys have documentation of what the parameters should be.   I tried to see the code, but I can't find the specifics of 'pointscount', 'interval' etc ... @JonathanNathanson

Comment: I'm not aware of any official documentation, but there's some comments in the NPM package code I suggested that might be helpful. [Check it out at line 31 on index.js](https://github.com/DavideViolante/investing-com-api/blob/a5c40731858e74db5d5edc51ec43e258d14b41aa/index.js#L31)